# Supplier creation API In Oracle R11i

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-ebs

Does anybody has idea on api to create supplier for Oracle R11i. Please advice.

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer**: there is a PL/SQL API for creating suppliers in the `AP_VENDOR_PUB_PKG` package.

**Long answer**: Oracle EBS has an integration repository you can browse via the applications.  If you are lazy, like me, you can also query the integration repository data directly from SQL via the `FND_IREP_CLASSES_VL` view.

Since we are looking for a PL/SQL API first (maybe we'll settle for a Java or a Concurrent Program API if there is no PL/SQL API, but we'll start with PL/SQL) and since we can guess that an API to create suppliers is either going to be owned by the Purchasing (PO) or Payables (AP) module, our query looks like this:

```
select product_code, class_name 
from fnd_irep_classes_vl
where product_code in ('po','ap')
and class_type = 'PLSQL';
```

> ```
> +--------------+---------------------------------+
> | PRODUCT_CODE |           CLASS_NAME            |
> +--------------+---------------------------------+
> | ap           | PLSQL:AP_UTILITIES_PKG          |
> | ap           | PLSQL:AP_VENDOR_PUB_PKG         |
> | po           | PLSQL:PO_DOCUMENT_CONTROL_PUB   |
> | po           | PLSQL:PO_ASL_API_PUB            |
> | po           | PLSQL:PO_REQUISITION_UPDATE_PUB |
> | po           | PLSQL:PO_CHANGE_API1_S          |
> | po           | PLSQL:PO_CUSTOM_PRICE_PUB       |
> +--------------+---------------------------------+
> ```

Looking at that list, we see `AP_VENDOR_PUB_PKG`, which looks promising.  So we open up that package and see its comments:

```
/*
 * This Package provides APIs to allow users to create supplier,
 * supplier site and supplier contact records into Payables.
 * ...
 */
```

Now, knowing the name, we go on the Oracle Support website and to the documentation to get examples and learn how to use it, which I'll leave to you.

Comment: .. and I just realized I did this using my R12.2 instance and you wanted R11.  I don't have an R11 instance, but you should be able to follow the "long answer" process above to see whether that package is there.

Comment: I don't find table like fnd_irep_classes_vl and apart from that i do not find package or api called AP_VENDOR_PUB_PKG in R11i instance. I am having this in R12 but i am not sure on R11 that's why seeking help.